# How to get readable JSON after NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I have some code similar to this (I've simplified it here):

```
let text = "abc" let iosVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion

let message = ["Text" : text, "IosVersion" : iosVersion]

if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(message){

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/api/someapi")

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(message, options: nil, error: nil)


    print(data)

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = data

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: nil)

    task.resume()
}
```

This works fine, but I'd like to see the JSON in a readable format so that I can copy/paste it into fiddler/curl to help diagnose my API at the server end. The `println(data)` line above gives me hexadecimal data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a `String` from `Data` and it's good practice to handle the error

```
do {
  let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message)
  let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
  print(dataString)

  // do other stuff on success

} catch {
  print("JSON serialization failed: ", error)
}
```

Comment: ... and use that string for debugging purposes and nothing else.

Comment: In Swift 2, var error : NSError?
if let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(message, options: nil, error: &error) => is wrong with error: "Extra agrument 'error' in call". How you fix?

Comment: I'm not goint to catch and crash directly if the message is nil. should have check the message as? [String: Any] before doing serialization.

Comment: The object from which to generate JSON data. Must not be nil.
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data